# from a JSON file such as adding the attributes of the Actions class to a queue in order in JAVA using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson-databind

from a JSON file such as adding the attributes of the Actions class to a queue in order, to consume them in order.

JSON PARSER: jackson-databind

JSON FILE:

```
{
  "name": "sampleName",
  "url": "www.google.com",
  "dir": "C:\\Users\\user\\Java\\project\\file.json",
  "actions": {
    "wait": 3,
    "click": "route",
    "write": {
      "route": "I'm a Path HTML Example",
      "text": "i'm a example text"
    },
    "enter": "enter",
    "tab": "tab"
  }
}
```

This is my class, i need save in queue the actions for consume in order

Action.Class

```
public class Actions {

    private int wait;
    private String click;
    private Map<String, Object> write;
    private String enter;
    private String tab;

    @JsonProperty("wait")
    public int getWait(){
        return wait;
    }

    public void setWait(int wait) {
        this.wait = wait;
    }

    @JsonProperty("click")
    public String getClick() {
        return click;
    }

    public void setClick(String click) {
        this.click = click;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getWrite() {
        return write;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setWrite(Map<String, Object> write) {
        this.write = write;
    }

    @JsonProperty("enter")
    public String getEnter() {
        return enter;
    }


    public void setEnter(String enter) {
        this.enter = enter;
    }

    @JsonProperty("tab")
    public String getTab() {
        return tab;
    }

    public void setTab(String tab) {
        this.tab = tab;
    }

}
```

.............................................................

...........................

Comment: Use ObjectMapper to deserialise it and add it to a Queue. What help you needed here ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.